# Maîtrise ou Proficiency

Tags: académique, université

"Certificate of Proficiency in English" [[1]](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_of_Proficiency_in_English). Dans un exposé, faut-il traduire le titre du diplôme en français ou pas ? E.g., *maîtrise en anglais* serait-il compris ?

Le cas échéant, comment peut-on faire la distinction entre *maîtrise en anglais* et *maîtrise en physique* (Bac+4 : La maîtrise est un ancien diplôme français et un grade universitaire de second cycle de l’enseignement supérieur, validant la quatrième ou cinquième année d'études après le baccalauréat, et une ou deux années d'études supplémentaires après la licence.) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu utilises *en*, ça signifie que tu as obtenu un diplôme nommé maîtrise.

> Maîtrise en anglais

Si tu utilises *de*, ça signifie que tu as un très bon niveau dans la discipline.

> Maîtrise de l'anglais

Dans les deux cas, le mieux est d'indiquer entre parenthèses et en anglais le diplôme effectivement détenu.